# Android: Parse Server save Error 111: This is an invalid Polygon

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a GeoPolygon into my Parse server using an android app but I keep getting an:

error 111: this is not a valid polygon

this is my code:

```
//create the parse object
ParseObject obj = new ParseObject("SomeClass");

List<ParseGeoPoint> geoPoints = new ArrayList<ParseGeoPoint>();
geoPoints.add(new ParseGeoPoint(1.468074, 110.429638));
geoPoints.add(new ParseGeoPoint(1.468075, 110.429287));
geoPoints.add(new ParseGeoPoint(1.467376, 110.429681));
geoPoints.add(new ParseGeoPoint(1.467373, 110.429283));

ParsePolygon geoPolygon = new ParsePolygon(geoPoints);

obj.put("Boundaries", geoPolygon);
obj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Geo Polygon save complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Geo Polygon save failed. error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I followed the Docs for geopolygons here:

http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#parsepolygon

and somehow, even when I copy pasted the code provided in the docs, it doesnt work.
Any suggestions/ solutions are most welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe not many people may see this but I'll post my solution to this anyway.

The issue was solved after I updated the version of my Parse Server. I didn't note which version I updated the Parse Server from but my current Parse Server is now v2.7.1 .

Previous/ older version of Parse Server does not support geo-Polygons.